# Using Apple's Transporter on Windows

Tags: ios, deployment

So on the [Transporter documentation page](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html#apdAe41970bd) they say you can download Transporter on Windows. But all I see are options for books, TV shows, movies etc. And if I click those, I can't seem to find it anyways. So are we really able to use Transporter to deploy apps on Windows or not?

Answer (score 6):

From my experience, that is because you are not logged into an Apple ID that is currently enrolled in the Apple Developer Program. Follow these steps:

1. Enroll as an Individual here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/
2. Once you are enrolled, be sure to log into developer.apple.com
3. Now click the download link documented on the transporter documentation page: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/Transporter__Windows/bin

This *should* solve your issue. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I installed the OSX on VMWare to use Transporter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Installing OSX on non-Apple hardware is a breach of their legal terms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to download the Transporter installer for Windows on this page (no account needed)
https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html

Direct links:

Windows:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/public/Transporter__Windows/bin

Linux:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/public/Transporter__Linux/bin

Comment: The linux link works but the windows link is broken, with message "Unexpected Error"

Comment: I just checked and I can still download both files

Comment: Thanks. Yes I managed to download it too. It was only broken temporarily.